# SSRS report parameters

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

In my SSRS report there are 2 parameters called DataSourceIDList and ReporterIDlist.

DataSourceIDList : is a drop down list and this will populate based on SQL query.

ReporterIDlist : is a drop down list and this will populate reporters based on selected Datasourceid from DataSourceIDList and this is also a SQL query.

both parameters are optional fields but when i am running the report  i am getting error called "Please select value for DataSourceID" but i set the property for that parameter as allow NULL values

and same problem for ReporterIDlist also.

Please suggest your suggestion....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Basically i need to RUN the report without selecting any parameter from drop downs. IF value is not selected, the SQL procedure will return all details of all Datasources....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that SSRS will not allow you NULL value if parameter have datasource.

Trick that I do when I need all values that is: I change data source for parameters that is in list have 
null, or ( 0) value, and option select ALL, and after that I set default value to null so users do not have to touch parameters before it call it

Something like this,

```
Select 1,null as ValueOfParam,'All values' as TextOfParam
union all
select 2,id,name from myDatasourceThatHaveParamValues
order by 1,name
```

Comment: I have one more question,
I have 2 date picker parameters are in report, I want give a warning when user select second date with out selecting the first date

Please advice

Comment: @VinnaKanna I am out of office till tomorow but I think that one of approuch is to set default value of second datepicke equal to value of first one so when  user change first date ssrs will enable second one and pay attention to user

Answer (score 0):

to verify date, you can use this method too:
make two rectangle; insert table/matrix in first rectangle
in second rectangle insert msg like 
"Selected Date is not valid, please select correct date"
or "Start Date should be less less than End Date"

put appropriate msg, and make condition in 1st rectangle where all tables/matrix is there

```
iif( Parameters!StartDate.Value < Parameters!EndDate.Value,false,true)
```

in second rectangle where Error msg is inserted write this:

```
iif( Parameters!StartDate.Value < Parameters!EndDate.Value,true,false)
```